# How to specify the row lables in r expss and not to use get(varname) as a label?

Tags: r, pivot, expss

when I was trying to use following code to pivot a group of variables which are named with a pattern:

## Loop through variables

```
tables <- list() 
pattern <- "aa_bb_cc" 
for (i in c(1:6)) { 
varname <-paste0(pattern,i) 
caption <- attributes(df)$variable.labels[varname]

# Create table for current variable
table <- df %>%
tab_cells(get(varname)) %>%
tab_total_row_position(total_row_position = "none") %>%

tab_cols(total(),s_Sex) %>% 
# tab_stat_cases() %>%
tab_stat_cpct() %>%
tab_pivot()%>%
tab_caption(caption)
tables[[i]] <- table

}
```

I got a table which has row lable as a combination of:

```
tables[[1]]$row_labels
```

[1] "get(varname)|Trifft voll und ganz zu"   "get(varname)|Trifft eher zu"
[3] "get(varname)|Weder - noch"              "get(varname)|Trifft eher nicht zu"
[5] "get(varname)|Trifft überhaupt nicht zu"

I would like to keep the only orginal levels from the data, is there a way in tab_* to turn off this paste setting ??

was trying to use some commands like :

var_lab, tab_row_label

dont work in this case

any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To suppress automatic labelling you can assign empty variable label to all variables in the dataset:

```
var_lab(df) = ""
```

or, make the same thing in the tab_cells:

```
tab_cells(set_var_lab(get(varname), ""))
```